# bundle install --without <group> with private git repository

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

I have a Gemfile which contains this group referencing a private repo that I don't have access to:

```
group :dpla_branding do
  gem 'dpla_frontend_assets', git: 'git@github.com:dpla/frontend-assets.git'
end
```

and when I try to do:

```
gem install --without dpla_branding
```

I get an error saying the Git repository is not accessible.  How can I get Bundler to not even try to access the repository?

If there's a way to change the Gemfile so that it works for both cases, I can submit a pull request to the upstream, but otherwise I'd prefer to avoid having developers edit the file.

Comment: why not comment out that line? since it is private repo you can't access it, that means you can't use that gem, so why not just remove it from gemfile?

Comment: Because it's a forked repo that I want to make changes to and pull requests on without having extraneous edits lying around.  Plus I'm documenting this for a "quickstart" doc and don't want users to have to add an extra step which is avoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the repository includes a `Gemfile.lock`, try including the `--deployment` flag:

```
gem install --deployment --without dpla_branding
```

The maintainer of Bundler indicated in [a comment on Bundler issue #1535](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1535#issuecomment-2738339) that this should work.

If you don't have a `Gemfile.lock`, you'll need to remove it from `Gemfile`, since Bundler needs to clone the gem to generate the lock file.

Comment: That works.  Thanks very much.  I never would have found that.  I'm not sure I accept the Bundler dev's comment about this being an unavoidable limitation, but this is good enough for my purposes.